# Watch for errors without returning error values? More info inside

Tags: c#, error-handling, try-catch

I am having trouble Googling this, so here is an explanation:

I want to execute a list of methods from another class, one after the other, and have all my error handling take place like a try-catch scenario.

Something like this:

```
try
{
    var thing1 = Worker.GetThing1(); //returns proper value, so continue
    var thing2 = Worker.GetThing2(); //throws error with message
    var thing3 = Worker.GetThing3(); //doesn't get done, stopped at 2
}
catch (ExceptionError errorMessage)
{
    MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
}
```

And the functions would look something like:

```
function GetThing1()
{
    if (!success)
    {
        throw ExceptionError("this is an error message.");
    }
}
```

The problem is I have no idea how to throw exceptions from another class, or if it is even possible to do.

Obviously, this is some serious pseudocode, so if I'm not being clear enough, let me know.

Comment: That looks fine. Except Worker.GetThing1 would throw in your example.

Comment: What is `ExceptionError`?

Comment: all looks fine ... could please elaborate your doubt. Or what is not working

Comment: If you want throw Exception with your custom message use `new Exception("Your message")`, other way your code looks fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the insight guys, I was so close with my original code. Here is what I ended up with:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var worker = new Worker();
        try
        {
            worker.GetThing1();
            worker.GetThing2();
            worker.GetThing3();
        }
        catch (Exception errorMessage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(errorMessage.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class Worker
{
    public void GetThing1()
    {
        var success = true;
        if (!success)
        {
            throw new Exception("This is an error message!");
        }


    }
    public void GetThing2()
    {

        var success = false;
        if (!success)
        {
            throw new Exception("This is an error message!");
        }

    }
    public void GetThing3()
    {

        var success = true;
        if (!success)
        {
            throw new Exception("This is an error message!");
        }

    }
}
```

It's so much easier to read and more efficient than trying to catch everything in `if-else`'s. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I made a quick console application to illustrate the point. The syntax for throwing a new error is `throw new Exception(message);` Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var thing1 = Program.GetThing1(); //returns proper value, so continue
            var thing2 = Program.GetThing2(); //throws error with message
            var thing3 = Program.GetThing3(); //doesn't get done, stopped at 2
        }
        catch (Exception errorMessage)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(errorMessage.Message);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool GetThing1()
    {
        bool success = true;

        if (!success)
        {
            // This will NOT be displayed in the console.
            throw new Exception("GetThing1 Error -> Not supposed to see this in output...");
        }

        return success;
    }

    private static bool GetThing2()
    {
        bool success = false;

        if (!success)
        {
            // This WILL be displayed in the console.
            throw new Exception("GetThing2 Error -> Expected, this has to be thrown!!!");
        }

        return success;
    }

    private static bool GetThing3()
    {
        bool success = true;

        if (!success)
        {
            // This will NOT be displayed in the console.
            throw new Exception("GetThing3 Error - > Not supposed to see this in output...");
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

To the guys saying 'all looks fine', please test your statements. Also, there is no standard class called `ExceptionError` in .NET, you can use the `Exception` class to catch all types of exceptions (but the poster said that he is using pseudocode, so we cannot hammer on the small details too much).

Comment: Why you say *"This will NOT be displayed in the console"*?

Comment: probably because it won't.

Comment: It won't be displayed in console, because the if statement will never allow it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have created custom exception class, and if your getthings function in diffrunt library than you should move this class to some common library and you should reference to both your libraries.